# The address of double pointer is deleted after assign some variable

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have an interesting problem after allocating a double-pointer.

```
int **bucket;
bucket = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
```

I have created a double-pointer without any problem and I have also created a single pointer.

```
int *size;
size = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
```

In the first loop, I allocated each element of `bucket`, and, second loop, I am assigning zero to every element of `size`.

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    *(bucket + i) = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 1);
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    size[i] = 0;
```

When I am doing assign operation to size, It deletes the address of certain elements of the bucket. Here, the screenshots while I am debugging.

In this stage I have not entered the 2nd loop:

[image]

This is after I entered the second loop:
[image]

What can cause this problem? Any thought?

Comment: `sizeof(int) != sizeof(int*)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem as I see it is

```
bucket = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
```

it should rather be

```
bucket = malloc (sizeof(*bucket) * 10);  // take the size from the target variable itself
```

In case, in your platform, `sizeof (int*)` is less than `sizeof(int)`, you'll end up having memory overrun while accessing `bucket`, thereby invoking undefined behaviour.

Notes:

1. [No need to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)
2. Better not to use a hard-coded type for size calculation.

Comment: If I do not use casting in front of the variable, It does not let me compile. Since I started university, I used this convention, I wrote above. they showed like this. That's, why I confused

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: @KaanTahaKöken: "*If I do not use casting in front of the variable, It does not let me compile.*" you then do not use a standard compliant C compiler, perhaps a C++ compiler?